# Infinite universe, big bang = no singularity?

Tags: general-relativity, big-bang, singularities

If we traced an infinite universe back in time towards t=0(ish) would a singularity still be formed?

Would the singularity be infinite in size? (To me it seems it would have to be) This reminds me of infinity x zero=....

Would an infinite singularity have some very unusual properties?

Also, how could an event horizon still exist if the singularity (at t=0) was spacially infinite?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but adresses the misconceptions lurking behind this question.

Comment: But I'm not suggesting that the singularity was formed at a single point.

Comment: From the accepted answer there: *"No matter how close we get to the Big Bang we still have an infinite grid filling all of space."* So, you're proposing nothing new - we already think the universe was infinite even very short times after the big bang, and talking about the "size" of the singularity is non-sensical.

Comment: That has to be the most linked question on the Physics SE. An afternoon's work well spent.